# Python: numpy.histogram plot

Tags: python, numpy, plot, histogram

I want to measure pixel intensities in a 16 bit image. Therefore I did a numpy histogram that shows the number of Pixels against the grayscale value from 0 to 65535 (16 bit). I did it with

```
hist= numpy.histogram(grayscaleimage.ravel(), 65536, [0, 65536])
```

After that I measure the whole intensity of my image with (that means the sum of : number of pixels * pixel value for each):

```
Intensity = 0
for i in range(len(hist[0])):
    Intensity += hist[0][i]*hist[1][i]
print(Intesity)
```

Now I want to see my histogram. I don't know how to plot `hist`, although I have my needed values. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Check out matplotlib? numpy.histogram documentation has an example right at the bottom.

Comment: Yes I checked that example and tried `bins = range (0, 65536) plt.hist (hist[0][i], bins) plt.show()` but nothing happens. Either a shown plot nor an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` directly for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(grayscaleimage.ravel(), bins=np.linspace(0, 65536, 1000))
plt.show()
```

Or use numpy like you already did and plot a barplot. However, you will have to set the width of the bars correctly by yourself and also skip the last bin entry so that it has the same dimension as the histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(grayscaleimage.ravel(), bins = np.linspace(0, 65536, 1000))
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, width=65536./1000)
plt.show()
```

I used only 1000 bins here, but you can also choose more, depending on the size of your image.

PS: If you want the total intensity, you do not have to iterate over all bins. You will get a more accurate result by just summing up all pixel values in your image `np.sum(grayscaleimage)`.

Comment: It works for me but it takes a lot of time even when I use a `100x100` image. You could try to increase the `1000` bins stepwise and chose a suitable value for your image.